# Generalizing the Definition of Convexity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

The definition of convexity can be given as:

**Definition:** Call a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^ k$, which will be denoted $E$, convex if given two elements of $E$, $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ and $0 < \lambda < 1$ the following holds:
$$ \lambda \boldsymbol{x} + (1 - \lambda ) \boldsymbol{y} \in E$$

What I have been wondering is whether this is limited to two elements of $E$. In other words, can this be generalized to $n$ elements of $E$ and still retain the same properties?

Thus I propose the following definition:

**Definition:** Call a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^ k$, which will be denoted $E$, "generally convex" if given $ \boldsymbol{x}_i \in E$, for $i = 1,2,...,n$ and the condition $\sum_{1=1}^n \lambda_i = 1$ the following holds:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \boldsymbol{x}_i  \in E $$

An open ball is an example of a convex set, and it is also the case that a ball is generally convex.

**Proof:** Let $| \boldsymbol{x} _1 - \boldsymbol{x} |$, $| \boldsymbol{x} _2 - \boldsymbol{x} |$, $...$, $| \boldsymbol{x} _n - \boldsymbol{x} |$, be $n$ balls centred at $\boldsymbol{x}$ with radius $r$. Consider the following:
$ | \sum_{i=1} ^n \lambda_i \boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{x} | $. This is also a ball of radius $r$.

$$| \sum_{i=1} ^n \lambda_i \boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{x} | = | \sum_{i=1} ^n \lambda_i (\boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{x}) | $$

$$\le  \sum_{i=1} ^n |\lambda_i (\boldsymbol{x}_i - \boldsymbol{x}) |$$

$$< \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i r $$

$$=r$$

This, among other things, satisfies both the definition for convexity and general convexity. This leads me to the following conjecture:

**Conjecture:** Consider a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^k$, $E$. $E$ is convex if and only if $E$ is generally convex.

I am having difficulty proving whether or not my conjecture is true.

My first thought was that given an element of $E$, it should be able to be expressed as a linear combination of other elements of $E$. And thus using this fact, expand the convexity definition to the general convexity one. The only difficulty with this is figuring out whether or not this can be done for every element of $E$. Online I have been able to find arguments that seem to support this for the case of vector-spaces, but nothing that states it for complex sets.

**Proof Sketch:** Suppose that it is the case that any $\boldsymbol{x}_i \in E$ may be expressed as a linear combination of other elements in $E$. Then given $\lambda \boldsymbol{x}$ as presented in the definition of convexity, the $\boldsymbol{x}$ can be "split" into two new elements of $E$. This can be re-iterated until we have the $n$ elements needed for the general convexity definition. Conversely, we just need to "combine" $\mathbb{x}_i$'s in the general convexity definition until only the two remaining elements we desire remain.

Thus this leads to my questions:

1. How do I go about proving whether my conjecture is true or false (linear combinations or some other method)?
2. Does this "general convexity" definition have any mathematical significance?

Comment: The conjecture is true, and because of that, general convexity has the same significance as convexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General convexity is equivalent to convexity.  This follows from a short induction proof.

Specifically, suppose $E$ is convex.  Then $E$ satisfies the general convexity condition for $n=2$.  Moreover, for any $n$, any points $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in E$, and any $0<\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n<1$ with $\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n=1$, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i \;=\; (1-\lambda_n)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_n} x_i\right) \,+\, \lambda_n x_n
$$
By the induction hypothesis, the quantity in parentheses lies in $E$, and therefore the quantity on the left lies in $E$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

"General convexity" or just convexity crops up a few times in the context of linear programming (more specifically, the simplex method).

In particular, because the feasible region of an LP is the convex hull of its extreme points, it's useful for proving that optimal values for an LP occur at the extreme points of the feasible region.